# Parámetros nulables en Método Virtual

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy implementado un método virtual, con 2 propiedades obligatorias. El resto, me gustaría poder declararlas como parámetros nulables, pero me estoy encontrando con el problema que al usar el método, me reclama que le pase un null. No entiendo muy bien por que.

El método virtual que tengo es el siguiente

```
private Param _param1;
private Param _param2;

public virtual void Metodo(Param param1, Param param2, Param param3 = null)
{
   _param2 = param1;
   _param2 = param2;
}
```

Entiendo que tanto `param1` y `param2` hay que pasarlos cuando sobrescribes el método, pero no entiendo porque me pide que le pase por obligación el `param3`, cuando esta inicializado a nulo

¿Alguna idea?

El ejemplo de como estoy sobrescribiendo es el siguiente

```
public override void Metodo(Param param1, Param param2, Param param3 = null)
{
    base.InitBindable(param1, param2);
    _param3 = param3;
    OtroMetodo();
}
```

En este caso se que tendría sentido, pero claro, ese metodo los uso en unos 10 sitios, y opcionales hay 8 parametros, por eso me gustaría poder ponerlos nulables y no pasarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del signo `?` después de especificar el tipo de dato de tu atributo, esto ayuda a especificar que ese atributo puede recibir valores nulos:

```
private Param? _param1;
private Param? _param2;

public virtual void Metodo(Param param1, Param param2, Param? param3 = null)
{
    _param2 = param1;
    _param2 = param2;
}
```

Entonces tu método override seria como:

```
public override void Metodo(Param param1, Param param2, Param? param3 = null)
{
    base.InitBindable(param1, param2);
    _param3 = param3;
    OtroMetodo();
}
```

Comment: No me dejaba utilizar el símbolo ? por la versión de C# que estaba utilizando. De todas formas, al final en la sobre escritura tienes que seguir metiendo el parámetro aunque sea nulo y es lo que me quería evitar